# Magento 2: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: magento2, javascript, overriding

I am trying to override magento 2 core js '

require-config.js file at path **Test/JsOverride/view/frontend/**

```
   var config = {
        "map": {
            "*": {
                "menu": "Test_JsOverride/js/menu-custom"
            }

        }
    };
```

**Test/JsOverride/view/frontend/web/js**

menu-custom.js

```
define([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'mage/menu'      ], function($){
    $.widget('inchoo.menu', $.mage.menu, {
        _init: function () {
            alert("I'm Inchoo");
        },
        toggle: function () {
            alert("I'm Inchoo");
        } }); return $.inchoo.menu; })
```

Comment: Did you run static content deploy?

Comment: Yes, I have run deploy

Comment: Can you check pub/static/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/en_US/Test_Override/js/menu-custom.js?

Comment: I found the file over there .

Comment: must be permission issue. or check .htaccess under static

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f; php bin/magento cache:flush;chmod -R 777 pub/static var/ generated/  I am using this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95010/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-paras-arora).